# NOT EXISTS doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgis

I have a table countries, and I want to display all the neighbouring countries to Sweden, and I got two problems.

My code is like this:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
FROM countries as a
JOIN countries as b
ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000
WHERE a.cntry_name='Sweden'
GROUP BY  b.cntry_name
```

It returned a table looks like this:

[image]

I want to delete Sweden from this table, so I tried to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
FROM countries as a
JOIN countries as b
ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000
WHERE a.cntry_name='Sweden' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT b.cntry_name FROM b WHERE b.cntry_name='Sweden')
GROUP BY b.cntry_name
```

However, this returned a blank webpage(I'm doing PostGIS online),which means there's something wrong in my code.

So the first question is, how can I delete the row Sweden after the selection?

Same thing happened when I tried to add `countries.svg` after `b.cntry_name`:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name,countries.svg
FROM countries as a
JOIN countries as b
ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000
WHERE a.cntry_name='Sweden'
GROUP BY  b.cntry_name
```

This also returned a blank webpage. Any tips where I went wrong when tried to display svg?

Comment: Why `ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000`?? Use ST_DWithin to allow it to use a spatial index, and make it much faster.

Comment: You can do this using ST_Touches, which will be more accurate than ST_Distance or ST_DWithin, both of which could give the wrong answer if you have a country 9999 m away that has no common border -- not the case with Sweden, but it could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
FROM countries as a
JOIN countries as b
ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000
WHERE a.cntry_name='Sweden'
  AND a.cntry_name <> b.cntry_name
--GROUP BY  b.cntry_name -- should work without GROUP BY
```

Comment: In your query there's no table named `countries` as you renamed them to aliases `a` and `b`. According to Standard SQL the query should fail with some "unknown table countries" errror

Comment: The distance query should be `ST_DWithin(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, 10000)`

Comment: @MikeTThanks for your tips,but ST_DWithin(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, 10000) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

skip your subquery:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
FROM countries as a
JOIN countries as b
ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)<10000
   AND b.cntry_name <> 'Sweden'
WHERE a.cntry_name <> 'Sweden'
GROUP BY b.cntry_name
```

explanation:

your subquery *always* returns rows ( since table `countries` has data on Sweden ), thus the where condition can never be fulfilled.

you also had a syntax error in your subquery, when you only gave the alias `b` in the `from` clause instead of the table name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all that would be necessary. `NOT EXISTS` is not necessary here:

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
  FROM countries as a
  JOIN countries as b
    ON ST_Distance(a.the_geom,b.the_geom) < 10000
   AND a.cntry_name != b.cntry_name
 WHERE a.cntry_name = 'Sweden'
 GROUP BY b.cntry_name
```

I think the `GROUP BY` at the end is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to find neighboring countries. There are places where borders are within 10km of each other, but the countries are not neighbors, so you would get false positives from the above. More correct, and shorter, would be to use [ST_Touches](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Touches.html).

```
SELECT b.cntry_name
FROM countries as a, countries as b
WHERE ST_Touches(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)
AND a.cntry_name = 'Sweden';
```